# How to use AdMob with some other Ad together in Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, admob, ads

I want to add AdMob to my cordova app, but heard that some other Ad networks may have higher eCPM while AdMob may have higher fill rate.

I am using this plugin:

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

After adding admob plugin, what shall I do next with the mediation?

Shall I configure something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1. you need install the mediation adapter in your app.

It can be simply done by running the cordova CLI:

```
cordova plugin install com.google.cordova.admob-iad
cordova plugin install com.google.cordova.admob-flurry
```

Build and publish the APP.

Step2, you need configure the mediation networks in your AdMob portal.

1. Click the menu 'Monetizae'.
2. Click your app at the left list.
3. On right side the ad unit list, click 'Edit mediation'.
4. Click 'New ad network', select 'iAd' and 'Flurry' from left side to the right side.

On right side, there are some parameters to configure for each ad network.

- For iAd, nothing to be configured.
- For Flurry, you need configure the Ad space name and API key you get from http://www.flurry.com/.